# ASP.NET Webform: Getting values of selected checkbox on codebehind

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have added a `check box` to the Jquery Datatable, can you please advise how can i get value of the selected `checkbox` on `button click` code behind.I am using `Asp.Net` `Webforms`. Thanks.

```
<input type='checkbox' value="xxx">
```

I expect to access the value of selected `checkbox` on `codebehind`

Comment: what have your tried. you need to post a full sample of what you have tried. otherwise people will start down voting your questions pretty quickly

Comment: if you just created the checkbox using jQuery, and it wasn't created at design-time with runat="server" tag then it won't be accessible by an ID, instead you would probably need to use Request.Form ...but first your element will need a name attribute (and make sure you don't duplicate the same name across multiple table rows, since you mentioned this is in a gridview context

Answer (score 0):

By using runat server you can easily get value of input tag.

```
<input type='checkbox' id="testID" value="xxx" runat="server">
```

Code Behind

```
string inputvalue = testID.Value;
```

Or you can use

```
<input type='checkbox' id="testID" value="xxx">
```

Code Behind

```
string inputvalue = Request.Form["testID"]
```

Comment: I think the checkbox (the one that's not runat=server) will need a name attribute as well before it will be visible to the server - that's a standard requirement for HTML forms (input elements without a name attribute are not submitted by the browser when the page posts back).